# Linear Independency of the List $[p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_m]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**Original Question**: My understanding from the book

Consider the following list

$$L=[p_0,p_1,p_2,...,p_m]$$

where $m$ is some nonnegative integer and $p_i$ is a function defined by

$$p_i=\{\,(z,z^i):z\in \Bbb{F}\,\}, \text{ for $i \in \Bbb{W}$}$$

that $\Bbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field and $\Bbb{W}=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$. Also, we have defined

$$
z^i=
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
z^{i-1}\cdot z & i \ne 0 \\
1& i=0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of the field $\mathbb{F}$.

Consider that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$. In fact, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is a subspace of the space of all functions $f:\mathbb{F} \to \mathbb{F}$.

How can I prove that the list $L$ in the linear space $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is linearly independent?

---

**Original Definition and Examples in the Book**: *Linear Algebra Done Right* by *Sheldon Axler*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "Linear independent"...in **what** vector space and over **what** field? Because $\;\Bbb F\;$ is a linear space over itself but of dimension $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: This is false if $z\in\mathbb{F}$, unless $m=1$, because $\alpha\cdot1+\beta\cdot z=0$, with $\alpha=-z$ and $\beta=1$.

Comment: In the problem statement $x\in\Bbb F$ is **given**. You cannot simply set it to $0$ (just look you cannot set $1=0$). But apart from this, you should first be clear about what your question is (as stated it makes no sense).

Comment: @DonAntonio: The field $\mathbb{F}$ is arbitrary but the vector space is the polynomial functions $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: Are you sure that $z$ is an element of $\Bbb F$? If so this set is obviously not independent. Now, if $z$ was in indeterminate over $\Bbb F$, that is if we were considering the _polynomials_ $1,\dots,z^m$ that would be different.

Comment: Ah. What you say in your comment is entirely different from what you said in your post! Again it raises a question: Are you _sure_ the question is about the space of polynomial functions? Because if you're actually talking about the space of polynomial functions, that set may or may not be independent, depending on $\Bbb F$. On the other hand if you're talking about the space of _polynomials_ over $\Bbb F$ then the set is independent. (Somewhere earlier in the book there should be an explanation of the difference between "polynomial" and "polynomial function"...)

Comment: @H.R. Then you should make that crystal clear in your question. Also, if $\;z\in\Bbb F\;$ then if you insist in taking it as a *vector* it is then a zero degree one, and thus $\;1,z,...,z^m\;$ are trivially linearly **dependent** for $\;m\ge1\;$ ...I don't think this is what you were trying to ask.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: It seems that I am reading too carelessly! :) Let me check. I think $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{F})$ is set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$. I am a little confused! :)

Comment: Example: Say $\Bbb F=\Bbb Z_2$, the field with two elements. If we're talking about _polynomial functions_ then $z+z^2=0$, so those functions are not independent. But if we're  talking about _polynomials_ then those poynomials _are_ independent. ($z+z^2$ is a non-zero polynomial. Not that that proves independence.)

Comment: Assuming it is the space of polynomials (i.e. $\Bbb F[z]$). I would try differentiating both sides of equation 2, then plugging in zero, and repeating.

Comment: @Dave ??? If we're actually talking about polynomials then there's no need for that; $c_0+\dots+c_mz^m$ is non-zero just by the definition of "polynomial", unless all the $c_j$ vanish. Your comment might make sense for polynomial functions; but for polynomial functions the result in question is false, in general.

Comment: If you want to check that this set (as a set of polynomial functions) with $\mathbb{F}$ being the real or complex numbers is LI, just evaluate the Wronskian.

Comment: I just noticed that you've _said_ you think you're talking about polynomials, and you've also _said_ you think you're talking about polynomial functions. In case you've missed it: When you check, check very carefully! Because polynomials and polynomial functions are totally different things.

Comment: The edit still says that $z$ is an element of $\Bbb F$. If $z$ is an element of $\Bbb F$ then the result is obviiously false. Also if $z$ is an element of $\Bbb F$ then $z$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Hint, once you decide that it really is a question about polynomials: What was the _definition_ of "polynomial"? (Hint: By _definition_ the polynomial $c_0+\dots+c_mz^m$ is equal to the sequence $(c_0,c_1,\dots,c_m,0,0,0,\dots)$. I mean _equal_; that polynomial and that sequence are exactly the same thing!)

Comment: And btw this is why if we're talking about polynomials then $z$ is not an element of $\Bbb F$: _By definition_ $z=(0,1,0,0,0,\dots)$. That's a sequence of elements of $\Bbb F$, not an element of $\Bbb F$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks for the comprehensive comments! :) I just got headache while reading *Linear Algebra Done Right*! :D I will post the original things defined in the book! :)

Comment: I just noticed something else: You say that $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ is the space of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb F$. _Then_ you say that $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$ is a subspace of the space of all functions from $\Bbb F$ to itself. **THIS IS NOT TRUE** An element of the space of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb F$ is _not_ a function from $\Bbb F$ to itself. This problem is impossible until you get the difference between "polynomail" and "polynoial function" straight.

Comment: Oh dear, elementary linear algebra. You said $\Bbb F$ is a field. Can it be any field, or is it one of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$? Makes a big difference... (I've been saying over and over that those _polynomial functions_ are _not_ independent. If $\Bbb F$ is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ then they _are_ independent.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: The book does not restrict the discussion to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ in the first three chapters! Can you take a look at the original thing in the book that I added to the post. :)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. First, the definitionn in the book is really the definition of "polynomial function", not "polynomial". The difference doesn't usually matter much at that level, _because_ usually we're talking about the real or complex fields. But if we're allowing any field then part (d) is simply false. There's a counterexample in one of my comments above - if $\Bbb F$ is the field with two elements (and we're talking about polynomial functions) then $z+z^2=0$.

Comment: Which book is this exactly? I know one book that defines polynomial as polynomial functions and states things like this. That seems absurd, until one looks at its definition of _field_, which it defines as a **subset of the complex numbers** closed under all 4 arithmetic operations (excepting division by 0). While that contradicts the generally accepted definition of a field, it does allow confusing polynomials and polynomial functions without harm.

Comment: Also please, please remove the part $z\in\Bbb F$ from the question it is wrong (what is meant by $z$ is the "polynomial" (i.e., function) $p$ with $p(z)=z$ for all $z$, in other words the identity function $\Bbb F\to\Bbb F$). [I find this kind of notation quite perverse.]

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: The book is *Linear Algebra Done Right*. By the way, I am reading an elementary linear algebra book and every one is just saying complicated things that I don't understand! :D I don't know the difference between *Polynomial* and *Polynomial Functions* as the book said nothing about them. Also why $z\in\Bbb F$ is wrong? I will be really thankful if you write an answer pointing out the things that I should know. :)

Comment: Do you know what abstract algebra is? I suspect not. If not then including that tag was a bad idea - the reason people are assuming you understand all those things is they assume you're studying abstract algebra.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Maybe you are right! :) But the aim of the book is to teach a little abstract things too! My understanding of abstract is working with some elements that we don't know what they really are but we know about some of their important properties! :) However, I think the main part of confusion is due the book! Can you write an answer mentioning all the mistakes I  made and the things I must know to handle this question, please? :) I will be so thankful. :)

Comment: Abstract algebra is a specific mathematical subject, not just "abstract things". I've already said everything I have to say in the comments - if $\Bbb F$ can be any field then (d) is wrong. (Do you know what a _field_ is?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I know [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration) about fields. :)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Is the notation OK now? :)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Can I ask that what would be a condition for a *nice* $\mathbb{F}$ that $(d)$ is true? :) Also, in that case how can I prove that $(d)$ is true? :)

Comment: I've corrected one last glitch in the formulation. But by making everything so precise (notably defining polynomials as functions and insisting that $\Bbb F$ could be an _arbitrary_ field), the linear independence that you want to prove is **not true** in general. It it true though whenever $\Bbb F$ is an _infinite field_ (and for fixed $m$ it is true provided $\Bbb F$ has strictly more than $m$ elements).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Many Thanks Prof. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong (in the book):

1. The Definition of *polynomial* is not what is commonly called a polynomial; normally, this would rather be called a *polynomial function*.
2. The polynomial functions $z\mapsto 1, z\mapsto z, \ldots, z\mapsto z^m$ are not necessarily linearly independent.

To see the second point, consider the case that $\Bbb F$ is the field of two elements (or any finite field and adjust the following numbers). Then there are only **four** functions $\Bbb F\to \Bbb F$ to begin with. Hence, $\mathcal P(\Bbb F)$, which is a subset of $\Bbb F^{\Bbb F}$ also has at most four elements. Thus for $m\ge 4$, the elements of the list $[p_0,\ldots, p_m]$ cannot even be distinct, let alone linearly independent.

However, if your field $\Bbb F$ has infinite cardinality, then yes, these functio0ns are linearly independent: Any linear dependence, i.e., a non-trivial linear combination of the monomial functions would result in a polynomial function that is identically zero on all of $\Bbb F$. That is, we have a polynomial with infinitely many zeroes. Only the zero polynomial has this property.

Comment: In my book, the field $\mathbf{F}$ is explicitly defined to be either the field of real numbers or the field of complex numbers. Thus it’s possible to think of a polynomial as a function from $\mathbf{F}$ to $\mathbf{F}$, which has the pedagogical advantage of being a familiar object to students.

Comment: @SheldonAxler: At the end of section $1.A$ (Digression on Fields), you said that "In this book we will not need to deal with fields other than $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. However, many of the definitions, theorems, and proofs in linear algebra that work for both $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ also work without change for arbitrary fields. **If you prefer to do so, throughout Chapters 1,2, and 3 you can think of $\Bbb{F}$ as denoting an arbitrary field instead of $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$**, except that some of the examples and exercises require that for each positive integer $n$ we have $1+1+...+1 \ne 0$."

Comment: @SheldonAxler: *A suggestion*: In page $45$, in the box, you mention a really nice point. "Thus when we talk about the dimension of a vector space, the role played by the choice of $\Bbb{F}$ cannot be neglected." I think this post mentioned here can be used to emphasize the role of $\Bbb{F}$ in the concept of Linear Dependence. :)

Comment: Let me clear up some misinformation, because one of the comments above states that my book Linear Algebra Done Right “does not restrict the discussion to $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ in the first three chapters.” In fact, starting with Chapter 2, the first page of every chapter in the book prominently states in a box that “$\mathbf{F}$ denotes $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$.” The book includes a comment at the end of Chapter 1 that “many” of the results hold for arbitrary fields, but the book explicitly states that some of them require that the field have characteristic 0.

Comment: @SheldonAxler: You are right! :) But it will be much instructive and efficient if you **highlight** these examples and theorems in the text in the first three (or maybe two) chapters. The reason is that they are not too many and they can contain nice points like this one that emphasizes the role of $\Bbb{F}$ in the concept of linear dependence. Also, it can avoid confusions for those who may want to think of $\Bbb{F}$ as arbitrary fields. :)